# how to get next ID in a table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table that has following columns

```
id   store_id   store_name
```

`id` and `store_id` are always going to be same. Since I am new to rails...I had created it by mistake.  But I can't afford to go back and change stuff now since I am using `store_id` at a lot of places.

**Issue 1:** I am making admin screen for this table.  When I try to insert a record, eventhough, `id` gets inserted (rails automatically gets the next one) `NULL` is being inserted in `store_id`.

Is there any ways I can have same number in `store_id` as in `id` while inserting record using the create method. Is there something that can be put in the model so that it is always execute before creating a record. and there I can have access to the next `Id` that should be inserted?

**Issue 2:** Since I am making admin screens for this table now..before I was just inserting data into this table by hand.  I have inserted 5 records by hand so `id` and `store_id` 1..5 already exist.  Now when I try to insert a record from admin screen it says duplicate key violates constraint. could it be trying to insert id of 1 since this is the first time I am inserting record to this table using rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue 1**: Until you can remove the `store_id` column, override the getter in the model for compatibility.

```
def store_id
  id
end
```

As for **Issue 2**: make sure your create code is not manually setting the `id`. The next record *should* be inserted with id 6, as long as your object has no id defined. Try it from `script/console`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just change your code to only use the ID. 
A competent editor will be able to tell you where you have used store id in your project, and your tests will help if you introduce a regression error.

Otherwise, you could use a database trigger. Or setup a callback on the model to set store_id from the newly created id value (look at the **after_create** callback). Again, both of these approaches are hacks to cover up a bug in your system with an easy fix.

Comment: if I use after_create will it have an update query..to update the created record

Comment: You don't know the ID until after the record is created. This is simply how the database works.

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom primary key for ActiveRecord models:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :store_id
end
```

Then you can create a new migration that removes 'id' column and updates 'store_id' column to be a primary key.